# How do i go to a folder in python to execute a python script there?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm using the pi_video_looper to loop videos on raspberry pi start. Because I want to use more raspberry pis, and change the videos some times, i changed the program so it would get the videos from a NAS server.

The problem is, that it woun't mount properly. So every time I restart the pi i have to stop the video looper from another computer (`sudo supervisorctl stop video_looper`), mount the pi again (`sudo mount -a`) and restart the video looper (`cd /home/pi/pi_video_looper; sudo ./install.sh`).

I tried to write a python script that would simply write the commands into terminal (with `os.system`). This almost works. The only thing is, that the install.sh doesn't work properly when I start it from "home". So I need a command that would do the same as `cd /home/pi/pi_video_looper` so I can execute install.sh directly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check out `os.chdir`. With that said, why not use a bash script for this? A script with all of this in one file would be most simple.

Comment: I will try os.chdir in a sec. But could you explain the bash script a bit more? Sorry, but I'm almost competely new to it...

Comment: A bash script is simply a sequence of commands to be executed by your shell (`bash` by default). Throw your commands in a file, add an executable permission to it with `chmod`, and go ahead and run it. Check out https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Ok. os.chdir somehow doesn't work, but I'll try out the bash script. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Wow, could have been so easy... :D But one more (stupid) question: How do I make it start some time after startup? (I need to wait till the program started, so like 20s or so). I've read some things about `rc.local`, but that only works ON startup, right? @ollien

Comment: Easiest way is to just do a "sleep 20" as the first line in the script. ps. probably want to ask this sort of thing on https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com